# Does Ubuntu use the IOMMU or can it be activated?

Tags: hardware, ram, devices, amd-processor, firmware

I have an AMD chipset and CPU with an integrated IOMMU (AMD I/O Virtualization Technology). Recently, I read that these chips can be used by the system to prevent access to the full physical memory by peripherial devices, in order to prevent malicious functionality or enhance privacy, as the devices are only able to access their specific portion of the system memory.

Is my IOMMU already utilized by Ubuntu (16.04) or is there a way to activate this functionality?

Comment: check the results of `dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU` and `find /sys/kernel/iommu_groups/ -type l`. 16.04 should have it enabled. You do need to connect a monitor to the GPU that will be active on boot -and- to the monitor that will be used in the pass-through.